# Implementing Static Libraries In iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I have created a static library following [this link](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html).

But I am facing Problems in using the library. For reference on how to use static libraries in an iPhone project I followed [this link](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/) .

But I am stil struggling with the "How to implement static libraries in any other iPhone project?" question.

Thank you all.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: This is a general Xcode problem, not iPhone only. I'd retag it with "xcode" at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use cross-project referencing as in the posts but this has several downturns.

I use this setup that works on Xcode in general (not only for the iPhone) and adds compile-time static library version control.

I put my static libraries in ~/Library/MyLibraries/, the .a archive along with their public headers. This way you can have different versions of them:

```
~/Library/MyLibraries/
                     /MyLib-1.0.0/Headers/header1.h
                                         /header2.h
                                 /libmylib.a
                                 /libmylib_debug.a
                     /MyOtherLib-2.1.0/Headers/...
                                      /libmyotherlib.a
```

Then in Xcode settings add the user variables:

```
LIBRARIES_DIR      $(USER_LIBRARY_DIR)/MyLibraries
MYLIBRARY_LIBROOT  $(LIBRARIES_DIR)/MyLib-1.0.0
```

and modify the settings

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS $(MYLIBRARY_LIBROOT)/Headers
OTHER_LDFLAGS       $(MYLIBRARY_LIBROOT)/libmylib.a
```

Now change MYLIBRARY_LIBROOT to choose your library version. More on this [blog post](http://danielepizzoni.it/2009/06/managing-static-versioned-libraries-in/) by me.

If you want to keep it simple then just compile the library and setup HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS and OTHER_LDFLAGS.

Comment: The drawback (which might be a benefit, depending on your needs) of this approach is that the static library will not automatically re-compile when you compile the projects that use them.

Comment: Certainly. But you want to develop and debug and test your library separately, that's the point of having a real library. You'll go out of sync soon anyway... ;)